# Implement HTTP methods in different APIView class in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an API with 2 routes `some_resource/` and `some_resource/<id>` and I would like to implement the normal CRUD actions (list, retrieve, create, update, delete). However, **I don't want to use ViewSet** because  I want to have 1 class for each view. Thus I need to set up the route manually for clarity. :

```py
class SomeResourceRetrieveView(APIView):
  def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

class SomeResourceListView(APIView):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

class SomeResourceCreateView(APIView):
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

So in urls.py it looks like this

```py
url_patterns = [
    path("some_resource/", InvitationTeamAccessListAPI.as_view(), name="some-resource-list"),
    path("some_resource/", InvitationTeamAccessCreateAPI.as_view(), name="some-resource-create"),
    path("some_resource/<int:pk>", InvitationTeamAccessRetrieveAPI.as_view(), name="some-resource-retrieve"),
]
```

However when I use POST on `some_resource/`, I get a 405. I think django stops at the first matched route and doesn't find an implementation for post. Is there a way to plug all my views to the same pattern but keep them as separate classes?

Comment: use different urls for different views for eg: use "some_resource/create" for post request..

Comment: I want to keep the API resource urls as rest as possible, so having different urls is not an option

Comment: did the below given answer worked for you?

Comment: Not really, I mentioned I don't want to use a ViewSet. The reason is that I don't want to use drf "magic" like get_queryset, get_serializer, etc...

Comment: I'm afraid what I'm looking for doesn't exist

Comment: i think the viewsets are the way, since you are dealing with the same model. also if you want you can write your own custom querysets in each viewset methods, like separate one for get() and post().

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [ViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

give this a try:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

class InvitationTeamAccessViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    Example empty viewset demonstrating the standard
    actions that will be handled by a router class.

    If you're using format suffixes, make sure to also include
    the `format=None` keyword argument for each action.
    """

    def list(self, request):
        # this is your get() method
        queryset = InvitationTeamAccess.objects.all()
        # you should change your serializer name accordingly 
        serializer = InvitationTeamAccessSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def create(self, request):
        # this is your post method
        # you have to write you post logic here
        pass

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        # this is your get() details method
        queryset = InvitationTeamAccess.get(pk=pk)
        # you should change your serializer name accordingly 
        serializer = InvitationTeamAccessSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)   

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        # write your post() method here
        pass

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

and in urls.py

```
from myapp.views import InvitationTeamAccess
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'some_resource/', InvitationTeamAccess, basename='InvitationTeamAccess')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

then with single url path you can perform multiple actions

> GET: some_resource/ will show the list of InvitationTeamAccess's
> GET: some_resource/1/ will show the detail of a single InvitationTeamAccess
> POST: some_resource/ will create new InvitationTeamAccess

also read about [ModelVieset](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)